# derby sometimes PreparedStatement slower than Statement

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, resultset, derby

I am using derby embbed version,there is a table with 100,000 records,when I use **PreparedStatement** query from it,the query is fast and just cost 200ms.
But the problem is when I fetch data from ResultSet,It's slow,takes about 1500 ms,but it's only 7 records in the resultset.
The first 7 records is fast,I think it should break the loop when all the 7 records have fetched completely,but it's not,the last excution of "resultset.next()" takes more than 1400ms.
On the other hand,I change to use **Statement instead of PreparedStatement**,when all 7 records have fetched out,the loop break immediately,plus the query time,all takes less than 200ms.I can't figure out the reason.

Comment: Don’t guess, use a profiler to find out where it spends most of the time. By the way, in the case of Derby I found myself often in the situation that Derby’s PreparedStatements do not improve performance at all.

Comment: I don't know if this helps, but perhaps.  Prepared statements require multiple round trips to the database.  First, to prepare the statement, then one trip for each bound parameter and finally an execute call.  In cases where no parameters are *ever* bound, sometimes a regular statement is slightly faster.  For example, "select sysdate from dual", a prepared statement won't help and may be slower (though we are talking in nanoseconds here).

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/PerformanceDiagnosisTips

http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.10/tuning/index.html

These should give you a place to start.